# Getting Linq query from the SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to get the Linq query from the SQL query. The sql query is:

```
Select * from EMP where Salary = (Select Max(Salary) from EMP)
```

I have created a Linq query, but it doesn't work at all:

```
var result = emps.where(emp => emp.Salary == emps.Max(emp.sal));
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, right - my mistake in copying the code :) I was mentioning "==" not "="

Comment: Also, `Max` takes a lambda expression like `emp => emp.Salary`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var maxsal = emps.Max(emp => emp.sal);
var result = emps.Where(e => e.sal == maxsal);
```

Comment: Wrong - your answer would be useful for the SQL Query: Select MAX(Salary) from emp.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help! What do you mean by //your columns?

Comment: the columns you want to select.

Comment: @KhairulIslam Presumably the OP wants all columns -- `SELECT * FROM EMP`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to do it as a single linq query, I think this will do what you're after:

```
var result = emps
    .Select(e => new { Emp = e, Max = emps.Max(_ => _.Salary)})
    .Where(e => e.Max == e.Emp.Salary)
    .Select(e => e.Emp);
```

** Update **
You can actually do that in the single statement:

```
var result = emps
    .Where(e => emps.Max(_ => _.Salary) == e.Salary);
```

Was there something else wrong with your original scenario?